# regular expression issue with condition - c#

Tags: regex

I have the following text from which I'd like to capture the first line:

```
text-to-capture: 1|5|3|5|2|1|0|1 
do-not-capture-this text
```

I'm using the following regex for that:

`text\-to\-capture:\s[^|][^\r\n]*`

The output should be:

`text-to-capture: 1|5|3|5|2|1|0|1`

However, sometimes, the first line might break with an equal sign (=), e.g:

```
text-to-capture: 1|5|3|5|2|1|=
0|1
do-not-capture-this text
```

Is there any way I can have one regex which will serve me in both cases (single line and two lines with an equal sign)?

I'm aware that the output with the line break will be

```
text-to-capture: 1|5|3|5|2|1|=
0|1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will it always be numbers separated by pipes or how can the data look like?

Comment: @EladT: Is the problem solved or do you need more help?

Comment: Yep... the following regex solved my problem: text-to-capture:\s[^\r\n=]*(=\r?\n[^\r\n]+)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text-to-capture:\s[^\r\n=]*(=\r?\n[^\r\n]+)?`

Match everything after `text-to-capture:` except a line break or an equals sign, then optionally match an equals sign, a line break and everything except a line break

Comment: Works perfectly!! Thanks... It also takes into account that the "=" is the first one...

Answer (score 0):

How about this;

`(text-to-capture:\s[^\r\n]*(?:=\n)?.+)`

It works with your second requirement

Thanks to Robin Gertenbach

Comment: That returns nothing without a linebreak and `=\n` with a line break

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`text-to-capture: (.*=\n.*|.*)`

It just captures everything after `text-to-capture`, and if there's an `=` at the end of line, captures it and the line after that.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `RegexOptions.Singleline` this may work for you:

```
text\-to\-capture:\s.*(?:(?<!=)[\r\n])
```

[test here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=text%5C-to%5C-capture%3A%5Cs.*(%3F%3A(%3F%3C!%3D)%5B%5Cr%5Cn%5D)&i=text-to-capture%3A%201%7C5%7C3%7C5%7C2%7C%3D%0D%0A1%7C0%7C1%0D%0Ado-not-capture-this%20text&o=s)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for both:

```
([^\|]*[0-9\|\n\=]+)
```

Explanation can be found [here.](https://regex101.com/r/hF8gC1/1)